# android WebView and web browser

Tags: android

I am opening a URL in web view. I want to prevent it from opeing in web browser. User may click anything it should be with in that web view. Can set that ? How ?

```
public class AcDetails extends  Activity {
private String url;

@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.acdetails);
    url = getIntent().getExtras().getString("AC");

    getWindow().setLayout(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT); 
    WebView wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webac);
    wv.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    wv.loadUrl(url);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to write a new class, just do it in-line:

```
WebView wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webac);
wv.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {  
             @Override  
             public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {  
                 view.loadUrl(url);
                 return false;
             }  

         });  
wv.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
wv.loadUrl(url);
```

Comment: little confused. From where should I pass "view" and "url" to that method. Shold I define "WebView wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webac);" and url inside that method ?

Comment: no problemo, funny i was just working on this today for my app

Answer (score 0):

http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-webview.html

You have to write a new class, which should extend the Webviewclient class:

```
private class HelloWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }
}
```

And change your code to:

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.acdetails);
    url = getIntent().getExtras().getString("AC");

    getWindow().setLayout(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT); 
    WebView wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webac);
    wv.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    wv.setWebViewClient(new HelloWebViewClient());
    wv.loadUrl(url);
   }
}
```

Comment: False! no new class needed, see my answer.